# How to setup InitelliJ to debug a Grails project?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I would like to utilize the IntelliJ Debugger with a Grails project.  The project uses the Jetty Web Server to execute on.  When I attempt to run the server side code with the debugger by setting a breakpoint, and then hitting the "Play" button, I get an error cannot find: junit.jar.

What do I need to get the Debugger to work?  A Groovy/Grails/IntelliJ Newbie.

Thanks.

Comment: what grails version do you run? can you provide your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I don't know why you are using a jetty web server. Don't you can use the embedded tomcat ?

Answer (score -1):

For using debugger in grails project :
Go to edit configuations and click on + button then select Grails.
Then fill in the details, name of configuration, choose your module and in command line option enter `run-app` then you are go to go.

I have always used tomcat so no idea about jetty.

Comment: he cant even run aplication because of problems with junit. Not mentioning that if he is using grails 3, he wont be able to debug application by running run-app. He should debug directly Application.main() or running bootRun task in debug mode.